# Add a symbol as suffix after detecting a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add suffix to the number with % instead of the current ₹ symbol in the front and also remove the .00 decimal points too. So the result shows as **9%** instead of **₹9.00**

I am not sure if one could modify this script to suit my needs. Here's my code:

```js
$('.percent').each(function() {
  var monetary_value = $(this).text();
  
  if ($.isNumeric(monetary_value) && (monetary_value < 100 || monetary_value.length == 2)) {
    var i = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'INR'
    }).format(monetary_value);
  }
  
  $(this).text(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percent">9</div>
```

**Demo JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p98aw6u/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require simply remove the usage of `Intl.NumberFormat()` and instead append the `%` character to the end of the value.

Also note the explicit conversion of the `val()` to an integer using `parseInt()` before being used in any comparisons.

```js
$('.percent').each(function() {
  var monetary_value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  var i;
  
  if (monetary_value && (monetary_value < 100 || monetary_value.length == 2)) {
    i = monetary_value + '%';
  }
  
  $(this).text(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="percent">9</div>
```

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much :) 
I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression might be the simplest way to do the job, depending on the input

```
const monetary_value = $(this).text(); // ₹9.00
const converted_value = monetary_value.match(/\d+?./)[1] + "%"
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match particularly since you should add some error checking to the above for when the match is null